# Why non greyed out commits aren't adding any differences at PR's diff tab?

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket, pull-request

I'm working on a BitBucket repository which has 3 main branches:

```
1. develop
    |  |
    |  |->release/7.10 (newer)
    |
    |->release/7.09 (older)
```

Automatic PR replication is activated in way that PR's pointing to `7.09` will be replicated to `7.10` and develop, while PR's to `7.10` will only replicate to `develop` like this diagram (numbers are chronological):

[image]

When moment 1 happens, moments 2 and 3 happens automatically. Replication takes code from right to left. Our develops create PR with their code from just created new branches (like the green arrow). But sometimes there are conflicts when the code is being replicated to other branches.

When moment 4 happened, it didn't successfully replicated into `7.10`. Before any other action, feature3 and feature4 were merged on `7.09` and entered the line of "code waiting conflict to be replicated".

Notice while `7.09` is fine with all features merged, `7.10` is a mess. If automatic replication PR generated at moment 5 were declined, the replication from moment 7 would be lost too and all code from feature3 and feature4 would be lost from automatic replicating. Thus, to solve this problem our developers create a new branch at moment 8 from `7.10`, pull code from `7.09` (with feature2 to feature4), resolve conflicts manually and creates a new PR that, when merged, automatically merges PR from moments 5 and 7 as shown at moment 9.

With this explained, let's go to the real problem:

1. A developer created a new PR to solve a replication conflict that were holding several commits from being applied to develop branch (the diagram above was showing this problem at `7.10`, this is the same, but on `develop` branch), including his own code. All the images are from the same PR:

[image]

2. He mistakenly added only conflicted files with a new single commit, solving his problem. But he ignored all the previous PR's that were blocked by his automatic replication conflict. Here's the changes from this new last single commit, the same as `All changes in this pull request`:
   [image]
3. Here are some of the commits from previous PR's that weren't automatically  replicated due conflict above:
   [image]

At the second picture, at the combo inside red rectangle, I could see diff from each commit listed on picture 3. But when `All changes in this pull request` was selected, it had last commit diff shown only. After this PR were merged, all the commits shown at 3rd picture were lost and had to be added manually per user. What happened with them and why they weren't replicated along conflicted files? If they weren't part of PR indeed, why they were listed as non greyed out commits?

Comment: I reply to the answer you linked. But why do you create new branch with new pullrequest to fix a previous pull request??? Why dont you just update the current pull request ??   And please draw some diagram we dont understand clearly wich pull request correspond to wich branch!!!

Comment: @user43968, I recently edited my question with new example and better explanation. Please, read carefully and if any doubts persist, please ask me

Comment: I don't really understand what the last picture really mean because we only see commit number and not what they are referring to if they are already merge I don't think they are in the PR or you are mixing PR. But I think you are making a big mistake by creating an other pull request to fix a previous one. A PR is a branch that need to be merged in an other while they aren't merging keep staying in the feature branch don't create another. And you are still saying approved for merged I think.

Comment: If he made a mistake you can still revert his commit and restart the process. Have you understand that PR aren't snapshot but just a view of the diff between one branch and an other ?

Comment: @user43968, last picture is just to show lots of non greyed out commits. They are from different people and are related to different files. The deal with creating new PR to solve conflicted ones is that the first is from `7.10` to `develop` and the solution for conflict is from `develop` to `develop` with code from `7.10` pulled in. Since the orange arrows are automatic replications, if file A conflicts from `7.10` to `develop` there's no way creating new PR from `7.10` will solve the problem. We had to deal with conflict where it's happening, i.e., `develop`

Comment: So I have reproduce your scenario, what do you really want to know? because your title ask about greyed out commit wich are already committed this is why they do not add diff. So what is the real question ?

Comment: First, @user43968, sorry for the delay and thanks for your patience and support. I'm interested into NON greyed out commits. I don't understand why, while they have their own diff content (couldn't show due copyrights), don't add this diff to `All changes in this pull request`. It's like they were a change that were noticed but not merged